# Discrete Mathematics - Probability card problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Question: Four cards, numbered $1, 2, 3,$ and $4$, are to be placed in four boxes numbered $1, 2, 3, 4$; one card in each box. Define a sample space of ordered quadruples that indicate the card in each slot. (For example, $12434$ indicates card $1$ in box $1$, card $2$ in box $2$, card $4$ in box $3$, and card $3$ in box $4$.) Using the sample space, calculate the probability that:

(a) exactly two card numbers and two box numbers coincide,

(b) at least two card numbers and two box numbers coincide, and

(c) no card number coincides with its box number.

-I am very confused on how to solve the question and which formula to use. I think the number part of the question is confusing me because I don't get how to solve for the probability. Can someone help out and explain the question to me? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a typo: "(For example, 12434 indicates card 1 in box 1, card 2 in box 2, card 4 in box 3, and card 3 in box 4.)"?

Comment: For a sample space this small, I strongly advise pen and paper, manual counting.  You can't attack a problem like this without stretching your intuition.  You can't stretch your intuition without manual exploration.  Therefore, why not kill two birds with one stone?

Comment: What he/she said. You don't use a formula for this problem. You just write evrything out, and count. If you see some patterns, you can invent your own formulas.

Comment: You may search derangement for further information after you are able to do the basic combinatorics counting.